# Triva Game, compare radio buttons value to answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm creating a Trivia game using an array of objects. I created a function that loops through and displays all the questions and then loops through all the choices and turns them into radio buttons. I've been struggling comparing the answer to the selected value, so when the timer runs out I can print how many the user got right and wrong. Can someone point me to correct direction?

```
function countdown() {
    var counter = 60;
    var timeCountdown = setInterval(function(){

      counter--
      $('.timer-container .time').html(counter);
      if (counter === 0) {
        clearInterval(timeCountdown);
        $('.timer-container .time').html("Times Up");
        points();
      }
    }, 1000);

    $('.timer-container').toggle();
}


let trivia = [
    {
        question: "How many wheels are on a skateboard?",
        choices: ["2",  "4", "6", "8"],
        answer: "2",
    },
    {
        question: "Who invented the kickflip?",
        choices: ["Tony Hawk", "Bam Magera", "Rodney Mullen", "Chad Muska"],
        answer: "Rodney Mullen"
    },
    {
        question: "Who did the first 900?",
        choices: ["Tony Hawk", "Tas Pappas", "Danny Way", "bob burnquist"],
        answer: "Tony Hawk",
    },
    {
        question: "What is another word for a 360 flip?",
        choices: ["Impossible Flip", "3 1/2 flip", "Tre Bomb", "Tri Flip"],
        answer: "Tre Bomb",
    }
];


function triviaQuestions() {
    for(var i = 0; i < trivia.length; i++) {   

        var questionHeader = $('<h2 class="question-' + i + '">');
        var questionHeaderContent = questionHeader.text(trivia[i].question);
        $('.question-container').append(questionHeaderContent).append("<form class='choices choices-container-" + i + " '>");

        for (var j = 0; j < trivia.length; j++) {
            console.log(trivia[i].choices[j]);
            var questionChoices = $('<input type="radio"' + 'name="'  + i + '"'+ 'value="' + trivia[i].choices[j] + '">' + '<label>' + trivia[i].choices[j] + '</label>');
            var questionChoicesContent = questionChoices.text(trivia[i].choices[j]);
            $('.choices-container-' + i).append(questionChoices).append(questionChoicesContent);

         } 
    }  
}




$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.start-button').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggle();
        countdown();
        triviaQuestions();
    });

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `points()` function could look something like this:

```
function points() {
    var correct = 0;
    $(".choices").each(function(i){
        var questionid = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
        var answer = $(this).find("input:checked").val();
        if (answer == trivia[questionid].answer) correct += 1;
    });
    $(".points-container").toggle();
    $(".points-container span").text(correct);
}
```

assuming you have an element somewhere on your page like this:

```
<div class="points-container" style="display:none">Total Points: <span></span></div>
```

**and** assuming you add the `id=""` attibute to your form elements:

```
$('.question-container').append(questionHeaderContent).append("<form class='choices choices-container-" + i + "' id='choices-" + i + "'>");
```

The function above loops through each form on your page, pulls the question's index in the trivia array from the form's id, and matches the answer given against the answer specified in that index. Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but it worked for me, with minimal edits to your code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit going on here so I've given you a complete solution - this covers the timer, the printing of the question/answer sets and the testing functionality.

A complete codepen here: https://codepen.io/V3Dev/pen/vYBaEVL

Details below - enjoy :)

HTML

```
<input id="trigger" type="button" value="Start Timer" onclick="startTimer();"/>
<p id="timer">60 Seconds Remaining</p>


<br>
<input id="trigger" type="button" value="Test Answers Immediately" onclick="testAnswers();"/>
<br><br><br>
<div id="container"/>
```

Script

```
//starting JSON
let trivia = [*JSON*];

//iterate over your JSON
for (let i = 0; i < trivia.length; i++) {

    //print the question
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(document.createTextNode(trivia[i].question));        
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

    //iterate over the choices and create answer objects
    for (let i2 = 0; i2 < trivia[i].choices.length; i2++) {

        //print the choices
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "radio";
        input.value = trivia[i].choices[i2];
        input.name = trivia[i].question;
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(input);
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(document.createTextNode(trivia[i].choices[i2]));
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

    };

    //seperate questions
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));


};

//test the submitted answer against the stored value
function testAnswers(){
    let score = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < trivia.length; i++) {
        let questionSelectedAnswer = getRadioValue(trivia[i].question);
        if (questionSelectedAnswer == trivia[i].answer){
            score++;
        }
    }
    alert("You scored " + score + "/" + trivia.length);
}

//get the selected value for a collection of answers
function getRadioValue(theRadioGroup)
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup);
    for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        if (elements[i].checked)
        {
            return elements[i].value;
        }
    }
}

//set the timer logic
var timer;

function startTimer() {
    //clear any running timers
    clearInterval(timer);

    var secondsRemaining = 60;

    timer = setInterval(function() {
    secondsRemaining--;

    // If the count down is over run the test
    if (secondsRemaining < 1) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        testAnswers();
        secondsRemaining = 0;
    }

    //print the time
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = secondsRemaining + " seconds remaining";

    }, 1000);

}
```